# How do I resolve peer dependeices

Tags: reactjs, react-native

> Targa 2 % npm install  npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE could
> not resolve npm ERR!  npm ERR! While resolving:
> react-native-multi-select-picker@1.0.11 npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
> npm ERR! node_modules/react npm ERR!   react@"17.0.2" from the root
> project npm ERR!   peer react@"*" from
> @react-native-community/checkbox@0.5.12 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@react-native-community/checkbox npm ERR!
> @react-native-community/checkbox@"^0.5.12" from the root project npm
> ERR!   40 more (@react-native-community/masked-view, ...) npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency: npm ERR! peer react@"16.8.6"
> from react-native-multi-select-picker@1.0.11 npm ERR!
> node_modules/react-native-multi-select-picker npm ERR!
> react-native-multi-select-picker@"^1.0.11" from the root project npm
> ERR!  npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.8.6 npm ERR!
> node_modules/react npm ERR!   peer react@"16.8.6" from
> react-native-multi-select-picker@1.0.11 npm ERR!
> node_modules/react-native-multi-select-picker npm ERR!
> react-native-multi-select-picker@"^1.0.11" from the root project npm
> ERR!  npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry npm ERR!
> this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps npm ERR! to accept an
> incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution. npm ERR!
> npm ERR!  npm ERR! For a full report see: npm ERR!
> /Users/digitivyindia/.npm/_logs/2023-03-16T21_20_55_720Z-eresolve-report.txt
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> /Users/digitivyindia/.npm/_logs/2023-03-16T21_20_55_720Z-debug-0.log

I tried to install npm dependencies but it is throwing me this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, we want to use the `--force` flag since this tells NPM to try to set a different peer dependency when it sees conflicting dependencies.

```
npm install --force
```

As for the `--legacy-peer-deps` flat, it tells NPM to ignore peer dependencies completely. This can stuff up your dependency resolution in the long run.

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```